# java memory performance - strange behaviour (or is this normal?)

Tags: java, memory-management, runtime, heap-memory

Hi there
I would like to start by saying that i'm a beginner, but i'm working on a really small and simple Java app, that really shouldn't cause some major problems.
I was monitoring memory usage from windows task manager, and noticed that with my application started, java.exe was using about 70MB of available memory. So I thought to myself, ok, this probably is a little large, but still, nothing that my PC couldn't handle. But really strange thing started happening when i tried to resize my window, memory usage suddenly jumped to like 80-90 MB, and if i would continue dragging my window, randomly resizing, it kept increasing memory usage. I thought it has something to do with calling repainting methods on GUI components during window resize, so i took a few suspicious components that could cause some kind of memory leak, and deleted those from my mainwindow form, leaving my program almost completely stripped down, but this issue persisted. What i noticed later was that if i keep resizing my window, memory usage grows up to 200-220 MB, and then stops this uncontrolled growth there. 
So can somebody tell me, could this be a normal behavior having in mind memory management in java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java objects created are not necessarily cleaned up once they're finished with. Instead, something called the "garbage collector" periodically runs in the background looking for orphaned objects and deletes them, freeing up memory.

Your application is likely creating lots of temporary objects as it resizes your window. Although no longer being referenced by anything (ie orphans), these objects are hanging around until the garbage collector runs.

You'll probably find that your max memory is 256M (the default) - the garbage collector is probably being called more often as you approach your max memory and the creation of new objects requires memory to be freed up immediately - hence the memory hovering just under 256M as the creation/deletion rate is balanced by demand.

This is completely normal behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

No, this behaviour is perfectly normal. Java memory management is based on automatic garbage collection, which means that unused memory accumulates for a while before being garbage collected (because that is a significant amount of work, you want to do it as rarely as possible.

So the JVM will tend to use a large part of the memory it's allowed to use (the maximum heap size) - and on a modern PC with multiple GBs of memory available, the default maximum heap size will be pretty big. However, if you have a small app that you know won't need much memory, you can adjust the maximum heap size via the command line option -Xmx, for example

```
java -Xmx64M main.class.name
```

will restrict the heap to 64MB

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot to you guys for your quick answers, appreciate that. Got to say that i really am introduced to all the basic concepts of java, including the principle of garbage collecting, only i dont have that much experience with developing java apps, so i dont have a "feel" of how it functions. Guess i could force the garbage collection at some point, but i see its not really a problem, i was just thinking that GC operates in a more frequent manner. Think i will set a limit on a heap in the end, if everything works out the way it should.

Comment: @Kani: garbage collection does actually occur more frequently, but there's another factor: the memory it frees will not be immediately returned as free to the OS. The JVM keeps it for itself in case it will need it again soon (because getting memory from the OS is also a relativel expensive operation). This behaviour can be tuned with some other (less well-known) command line switches.

Comment: Yes, this perfectly makes sense. I really should've read a little more about principles of garbage collecting before googleing about memory leakage issues :D